# Time diff in Amazon Athena / Presto (seconds and minutes )

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have  a list of creation time stamps and ending time stamps , i would like to get the amount of seconds last from creation to ending . could not find any way to do that  without using UNIX time stamp (which i dont have at the moment) .

something like that :

datediff('second',min(creation_time),max(ending_time))

creation_time = '2017-03-20 10:55:00' ..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**date_diff**

```
date_diff('second', min(creation_time),max(ending_time))
```

Comment: Thanks , seems like Athena have some different function that hiveql do no support .according  Hiveql documentation that wouldnt work but..in Athena it did.

Comment: "Athena is based on the Presto distributed SQL engine" https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-athena-interactive-sql-queries-for-data-in-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1):

`unix_timestam()` function converts date to seconds passed from `1970-01-01`

```
SELECT 
  (unix_timestamp('2017-03-20 10:55:00') - unix_timestamp('2017-03-20 10:56:00'))

OK
-60
```

Divide by 60 to get minutes

Edit: The solution above works in Hive. Presto does not have unix_timestamp as @nclark mentioned in the comment. There is to_unixtime function in Presto, it returns DOUBLE, so you need to cast it to bigint. The same logic in Presto:

```
CAST(to_unixtime(max(ending_time)) AS BIGINT) - CAST(to_unixtime(min(creation_time)) AS BIGINT)
```

Comment: `unix_timestamp` is apparently not supported in Athena or Presto, e.g. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=265717